# Questions and recommendations about Servlets

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I've started to do some programming using J2EE and I have a few questions in my project:

I have an index.jsp, a view.jsp and a servlet.

In the index.jsp when the user click a button it sends a POST to the servlet, which gets some data from the  database and does some calculations, and then redirects (using RequestDispatcher) to the view.jsp to show the results.

Is this a good practice? I mean if I had to display different kind of info on different JSPs, would creating a servlet for each "view" jsp be the way to go?

If I had to pass some info from the index.jsp to the view.jsp, would I have to pass the info to the servled and then on the servlet set the request attributes with the data obtained from the request parameters?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is first learn about MVC architecture using servlets and JSP and when you learn that, study for frameworks like struts, JSF.  You can start [here](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/)